# TensorFlow Object Detection API: Bounding Box coordinates and timestamp for video input

Tags: python, tensorflow, logging, object-detection, bounding-box

I am able to output the coordinates of the bounding boxes in the form [ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax] and have converted from the normalised form into a data frame with image coordinates.

I am wondering if there is a way I can log the bounding box coordinates to the terminal as the code is running with a timestamp from the video outlining the time each box is generated?

I am aiming to produce a data frame showing the bounding box coordinates accompanied by the video timestamp for when they are produced i.e. [box number, timestamp, ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax]

Relevant code is shown below:

```
with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    while cap.isOpened():
      ret, image_np = cap.read()
      if ret == True:
          image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
          image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
          boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
          scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
          classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
          num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
          (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
              [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
              feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
          vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
              image_np,
              np.squeeze(boxes),
              np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
              np.squeeze(scores),
              category_index,
              use_normalized_coordinates=True,
              line_thickness=8)
          out.write(image_np)
          cv2.imshow('Output',image_np)
          if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
              cv2.destroyAllWindows()
              break
      else:
          break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```